# Are there any primes for which $a^2 = pb^2 + 1$ does not exist?

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

The smallest solution to the above equation for various primes are:

$(p=2)$ $3^2 = 2*2^2 +1$

$(p=3)$ $2^2 = 2*1^2 +1$

$(p=5)$ $9^2 = 5*4^2 +1$

$(p=7)$ $8^2 = 7*3^2 +1$

Is there at least one solution for each prime?
If there is one solution, there are infinite.

Comment: Look up [_Pell's Equation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Pell's_equation) - in particular, the ontinued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{p}$ can be used to generate a minimal solution. (From the trivial 'base' solution $a=1, b=0$)

Comment: Lagrange showed that there is a solution for *all* nonsquare, nonnegative integers $p$.

Comment: Thanks very much. How do you find the continued fraction expansion of sqrt (p) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the recipe for finding a (all the ) solution(s) of the equation
$$a^2 - d b^2 = 1$$
where $d>0$ is a square free integer.

Consider the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{d}$. It will be of the form
$$\sqrt{d} = [q,\overline{q_1, q_2 , \ldots q_r}]$$
with $q = [\sqrt{d}]$, with the sequence $q_1 q_2 \ldots q_r$ repeating indefinitely ( a (mixed) periodic continued fraction). Assume $r$ is minimal with this property. Then the minimal solution of the equation will be $(a_1,b_1)$, where
$$\frac{a_1}{b_1} = [q,q_1, q_2 , \ldots q_{\epsilon r-1}] $$
where $\epsilon =1$ if $r$ even and $\epsilon=2$ otherwise.
All the solutions will be $(a_k, b_k)$ where
$$\frac{a_k}{b_k} = [q,q_1, q_2 , \ldots q_{k\epsilon r-1}]$$
Alternatively, $$(a_k + \sqrt{d} b_k ) = (a_1 + \sqrt{d} b_1)^k$$

Let's consider the example $d = 43= p_{14}$. We have the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{43}$:
$$\sqrt{43} = [6,\overline{1,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,1,12}]$$
Calculate
$$[6,1,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,1] = \frac{3482}{531}$$
 Fair enough, we see that 
$$3482^2 - 43 \cdot 531^2 = 12\,124\,324 - 43 \cdot 281\,961 =12\,124\,324 - 12\,124\,323=1$$

But then also
$$[6, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 12, 1, \
1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1] = \frac{168\,867\,574\,226}{25\,752\,063\,645}$$

and one can also check that 
$$168\,867\,574\,226^2 - 43\cdot 25\,752\,063\,645^2 =1$$

Of course, we have
$$(3482 + \sqrt{43}\cdot 531)^3 = 168\,867\,574\,226 + \sqrt{43}\cdot25\,752\,063\,645$$

so the only surprise might be that all the solutions are coming from the continued fraction, which is true.

$\bf{Added:}$ Now that I looked at the example of @Travis, let's see whether the theory works:

$$\sqrt{61} = [7, \overline{1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 14}]$$
The period $r =11$, odd, so we need to take chunks of lenght even multiple of $r$ $2kr$. The first one is
$$\frac{a_1}{b_1} = [7, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 14, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1]=\frac{1766319049}{226153980}$$
confirmed.

Note that if we take the chunk of lenght $11$ instead
$$\frac{a}{b} = [7, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1] = \frac{29718}{3805}$$
we get
$$29\,718- 61 \cdot 3\,805^2 = -1 $$

Answer (score 4):

If one permits a general positive integer $n$ in place of the prime $p$, the resulting equation (in integers $x, y$) is called *[Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation)*, and is usually rearranged to read
$$x^2 - n y^2 = 1.$$
Lagrange showed that there are solutions for all nonsquare $n$, and so in particular it holds for all prime $n$. Note that even for modest $n$ the fundamental solution (i.e., the one minimizing positive $x$) can be large. For $n = 61$, for example, the fundamental solution is $(1\,766\,319\,049, 226\,153\,980)$.

Comment: One can reduce that solution to a more bite-sized version by using the [_fundamental unit_](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalUnit.html), $U_{61}$ hence $$(U_{61})^6 = \big(\tfrac{39+5\sqrt{61}}{2}\big)^6 = 1766319049+226153980\sqrt{61}$$